# how to set custom date format for specific column in datagridview? - c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, date, datagridview

I am having many fields in a table.

Each field contains different data types i.e text, number, date/time.

I am displaying the table in datagridview.

Default date format is M/dd/yyyy.

But i want the date to display in a custom format i.e dd/M/yyyy in a datagridview.

I tried changing the format in default cell style as dd/M/yyyy. Now the date column works fine but the number columns are displaying as dd/M/yyyy.

```
string connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=database1.mdb;";
// select * from ~tablename~; 
string sql = "select * from table1";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
connection.Open();
dataadapter.Fill(ds, vehicleno);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
connection.Close();
```

How do I set custom date format for specific column in datagridview?

Comment: Can you show your code also? AFAIK, definition and displaying format info is column based. It shouldn't effect other columns if you do it properly.

Comment: All irrelevant code about your question would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this line after binding your data source:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["YourDateCol"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Where "YourDateCol" is the name of your date column in the database.

Comment: it works. Thank you. How do I sort that date column in ascending order?

Comment: @RaizeAhamed You're welcome.  If your data source were an IEnumerable, sorting would be easy with Linq's OrderBy method.  But I'm unfamiliar with any similar method for DataSet objects.  As such, since your data is coming directly from sql, your best bet may just be to alter your sql string to `select * from table1 order by yourDateCol`.

Comment: Thanks. Working perfectly. :)